# Flutter custom clipper

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was experimenting with custom clipper. I am trying to draw this curvy blue container. Somehow I cannot seem to figure out(currently a noob). Can I help with the code snippet of the paths of custom clipper? Most probably I am writing the paths wrong.

Here is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using custompaint calss

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>  {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomPaint(
          painter: BackgroundPaint(),
          child: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text("hello"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BackgroundPaint extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();
    Path path = Path();
    paint.color = Colors.white;
    path.lineTo(0, size.height *0.3);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.70, size.height*0.60, size.width*1.2, 0);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate != this;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankful for putting effort to provide the code and the output. 